# Is Jerry's face inspired by the kitten in The Milky Way?

Tags: animation, tom-and-jerry

I opened a [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Milky_Way_(1940_film))  article and as it's seen from the cover photo the brown kitten whose eyes are closed looks very much like Jerry from *Tom and Jerry*. The same facial patterns, the same eyebrows, and the same muzzle.

The [first](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puss_Gets_the_Boot) episode of *Tom and Jerry* (*Puss Gets the Boot*) (of course Tom's name was Jasper in it) came out at the same year as *The Milky Way* did, in 1940.

So is Jerry's face inspired from that brown kitten?

Comment: I think you're looking more at zeitgeist than direct inspiration. That was the style of the time.

Comment: The Milky Way first aired before the movie The Captain is a Lady, which came out June 21, 1940. Puss Gets the Boot was more than four months earlier - February 10, 1940.